# Call a php function when an html link is clicked

Tags: php

I want to call a PHP function when someone clicks an html link. I don't know how to do it. Please help.

```
<a href="" onclick="sendcode()">Didn't get a code?</a>
<?php
function sendCode(){
//code
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP is server side, HTML/JS is client side. In order for this to work, you would need a JS / AJAX function to execute on the click - making an additional request to the server via POST / GET request, you can not call a PHP method, as there is no longer a context of PHP on the client side device.

Comment: I am new to web development. Can you tell me how can I use AJAX?

Comment: Probably, Google also can, I gave you a place to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<a href="?sendcode=true">Didn't get a code?</a>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sendcode'])){
    sendCode();
}
function sendCode(){
    //code
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate this worked. Is there any flaw to using this? Any that I should know in terms of security?

Comment: This is most common way uses for run codes server side by a GET method request, and there is not any security issue while you are using this. most security issues come when you try to interact with databases or execute shell commands